# Creating a windows service to poll database

Tags: .net, windows-services

I've to create a windows service in .NET that polls a db table for any new records. If there is any new record then it should do some processing. I'm aware I can do that easily by timer, is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: that depends on your DB etc. - some DBs offer notification of new records for example...

Comment: that has notification feature so you can choose whether to poll or implement this push-based...

Comment: i want to know which one is better in what cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQl Server you could use Notification Services. You can write a query that shows retrieves some data and when the data changes an event will be sent to your application.

So instead of polling the database constantly you will have push based solution.

Here you can find some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

**[Edit]**

I'm working on the design of a windows service myself that will do regular synchronization between some external systems. That will happen once a day on a regular time interval. We don't need to be notified of individual changes so currently I'm not planning on using notification services. But in your case if updates can occur on any moment and you need to work with them immediately I think a push based approach is nicer.

Comment: Thanks that sounds good. It will be great if I get some guidelines that says when to go for timer based polling and when to go for this notification features? If I going to hit db less frequently then which one will be good choice?

Comment: Yes. They where introduced in SQL Server 2005.